# Conditional probabilitiy exercise.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ have a Poisson distribution with parameter $m$.  If $m$ is an experimental value of a random variable having a gamma distribution with $\alpha = 2,\  \beta = 1$ compute $P\{X = 0\}$.

This is an exercise in my Statistics text book.

I know the p.m.f. for the Poisson distribution and the p.d.f for gamma(2,1).  I also understand intuitively what the problem is asking for.  I also highly suspect from running experiments in Mathematica that the answer is 1/4.

I tried to integrate $e^{-m e^{-m}}$ from 0 to infinity but this was a total guess and the integral doesn't even converge.  I really do not know how to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: Is there a joint distribution for the $X$ with a gamma distribution? I don't think I understand why this is a conditional probability question...

Comment: The hint given in the exercise says to find an expression that represents the joint distribution of X and m.

Comment: @imu96 The question as stated in the first two lines implicitly says that $X\mid (M=m)$ has a Poisson$(m)$ distribution, where $M$ itself is Gamma distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $$P(X = 0) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}P(X = 0\mid m = t)f(t)\,dt$$

where $f(t)$ is probability density of Gamma$(2, 1)$ distribution.

We have $$P(X = 0\mid m = t) = e^{-t}$$
and  $$f(t) = te^{-t}$$
Substitution gives simple convergent integral. And yes, it converges to $1/4$.